# How to override or customize help command with App::Cmd?

Tags: perl

I have found [App::Cmd](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Cmd) very helpful for writing command line apps, but overriding the default commands is challenging. There are two default commands, which are `help` and `commands`. It appears that the `help` command parses the `opt_spec` definition in the subcommand class to generate a help menu in list form. For commands with numerous options, this default help menu is very difficult to understand.

What I would like is to override the `help` command to provide my own custom menu, or disable the `help` command completely and just allow a menu to be generated by options to a specific subcommand. The latter choice is easy to implement, but I would still like to disable the global `help` option in that case so that two different menus are not printed, depending on the position of the help option.

---

What I tried first is defining the `usage_desc` and `description` methods in the subcommand class (explained in the [App::Cmd::Command::help](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Cmd::Command::help) docs), but this just adds text to be printed before the options list. For example, adding a custom menu to `opt_spec` just causes two menus to be printed.

I also tried disabling the `help` plugin in my `MyApp::Command` class:

```
package MyApp::Command;

sub validate_args {
    my ( $self, $opt, $args ) = @_;
    $self->app->no_help_plugin;

    $self->validate( $opt, $args );
}
```

But this seems to have no effect. I also tried to modify the `default_command` method with no success. Without seeing examples it's hard to understand how to use these methods.

Can anyone can provide an example (or point to one on CPAN) of how to override or disable the global `help` command when using App::Cmd?

Comment: *Note: "help" is the default command, so if you do not load the default help plugin, you should provide your own or override the default_command method.* https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-Cmd/lib/App/Cmd.pm#new

Comment: @mpapec, do you mean try to define `help` in the subcommand class? I didn't try that, but I will now.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and the default menu is printed as before. I saw the statements about not loading the help plugin and providing your own help (see my post above), the question is how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem after a lot of experimentation. What the docs do not tell you is that if you disable the help plugin, you must also provide your own `default_command` and define it in the `opt_spec`. The docs say that you can provide your own default command OR override the default, but my finding is that you must do both to suppress warning messages. I'll provide an example.

In MyApp.pm:

```
package MyApp;

use App::Cmd::Setup -app;

sub global_opt_spec {
    return (
        [ 'man|m'  => "Get the manual entry for a command" ],
        [ 'help|h' => "Print some usage" ],
    );
}

sub help {
    print STDERR<<END

Usage:
myapp <command> [-h] [-m]
    -m --man    Get the manual entry for a command
    -h --help   Print some usage

Available commands:
   commands:    list the application's commands

 initialize:    A really useful description

END
}
```

In MyApp::Command::initialize:

```
package MyApp::Command::initialize;

use strict;
use warnings;
use MyApp -command;

sub opt_spec {
    return (    
        [ "file|f=s",   "A required file"],
    );
}

sub validate_args {
    my ($self, $opt, $args) = @_;

    my $command = __FILE__;
    if ($self->app->global_options->{man}) {
        system("perldoc $command");
    }
    elsif ($self->app->global_options->{help}) {
        $self->help;
     }
     else {
        $self->help and exit(0) unless $opt->{file};
    }
}

sub execute {
    my ($self, $opt, $args) = @_;

    exit(0) if $self->app->global_options->{man} ||
        $self->app->global_options->{help};

    my $result = _some_method($opt);
}

sub help {
    print STDERR<<END

Usage:
    myapp <command> [-h] [-m]
    -m --man    Get the manual entry for a command
    -h --help   Print some usage

Options:
    -f --file   A required file

END
}
```

In myapp:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use MyApp;

my $cmd = MyApp->new({ no_help_plugin => 1 });
$cmd->default_command( $cmd->help ) and exit unless @ARGV;
$cmd->run;
```

Now you can run `myapp` and it will generate the usage menu you provide. Because I have defined a `default_command`, the default help will just render your help menu and not complain about a missing command. Note that `myapp help initialize` will not be unrecognized now, so the usage would be the more familiar `myapp initialize -h`. The former command will just render the custom help that we want.

Also, now you have a unique menu for each subcommand. It is kind if ridiculous the amount of work this took for a simple example, compared to just writing your own script or classes, but for complicated commands this should make the usage much easier to understand.

I am open to suggestions for improving or simplifying this code, but it seems to do exactly what I want and work with what App::Cmd expects.